# Run mlflow project on multiple remote servers?

Tags: python, remote-server, mlflow

Can `MLflow` be used to dispatch **projects** to multiple remote servers?(not aws,azure etc.) from a local tracking server?
I have the following scenario-
Multiple servers, where I would like to dispatch the `mlflow` project to all with different parameters, and let them "report" back to the current **tracking server:**

```
for ip in servers_ips:
    start_remote_mlflow(entry_point=GITHUBPATH,tracking_server=this_server_ip,hparams)
```

I see one can dispatch `mlflow` projects to aws or azure by specifying the ip or the remote machine. Can it be done with desktops as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, MLflow is a centralized registry and tracking and is not responsible for distributred scheduling. You can use another frameworks and tools, like Dask or Luigi to accomplish this.